# Python: IndexError: index (7) out of range (0<=index<7) in dimension 0

Tags: python

this problem probably has a simple cause, but I don't see it now, and maybe someone else will run into a similar problem.

Once the program will be working, it will do american option pricing.
Here is the puzzle:

```
option_price = numpy.zeros(shape = (time_steps, time_steps))
stock_price = ... #computed earlier, as a matrix with the same dimensions as option_price
    if (putcall =='Put'):
        '''see if the option at that final price should have been executed or not'''
        option_price[time_steps-1, time_steps-1] = max([ (strike - stock_price[time_steps-1, time_steps-1]), 0])
        option_price[time_steps-1, time_steps-2] = max([ (strike - stock_price[time_steps-1, time_steps-2]), 0])
        '''recursively determine if the option at that time and price should have been executed or not'''
```

and when I call this method with time_steps = 8, the error message that I get is:

```
option_price[time_steps-1, time_steps-1] = max([ (strike - stock_price[time_steps-1, time_steps-1]), 0])
IndexError: index (7) out of range (0<=index<7) in dimension 0
```

After this message, I would try to fix the indexing - if I could see what is wrong with the current indexing. Is it forbidden to calculate entries of a matrix from a matrix with the same dimensions? Or is there some other problem which is only manifested this way?

Thank you very much in advance! I would highly appreciate if, instead of downvoting, you could say specifically what you don't like about this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the index range is 0<=index<7, that means that the dimension for that range is 7, not 8. Check what the shape of your matrix actually is at that time, and make sure it wasn't mistakenly created too small.

Answer (score 0):

Array starts with 0. So your first element 1 is array[0]. 8th element assume index out of bound. Because elem of 8 assume array[7] Sorry if this does not make sense. But array 7 element does not exists, the last element in array is merely array[6]...

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty self explanatory

```
IndexError: index (7) out of range (0<=index<7) in dimension 0
```

You asked for element 7, but the range is from 0 to 6.